# How to get to the previous fragment using jetpack navigation in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app with two fragments, which are home-fragment and youtube-fragment. When I press the "search" button, I can get to youtube-fragment properly. However, when I press the back button(the back on my phone instead of the back arrow in the toolbar), I just exit the app without getting any error or warning. I would like to get back to the home-fragment after press the back button.

Here is my code of both fragments:

**homeFragment**

```
package com.example.signlanguage_new

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.GridLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.signlanguage_new.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels {
        MyViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as SignLanguageApplication).database.VideoDao()
        )
    }
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner)
        {
            if(it==null) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "查無資料", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else
            {
                val action=HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToYoutubeFragment()
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {
            searchBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val search=binding.search.text.toString()
                if(search=="")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "請輸入關鍵字", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else
                {
                    viewModel.searchVideo(search)
                }
            }
        }
        val adapter=homeButtonAdapter{
            viewModel.category(it)
        }
        binding.recyclerView.adapter=adapter
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(this.context,2)
    }
}
```

**youtubeFragment**

```
package com.example.signlanguage_new

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.activity.addCallback
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.signlanguage_new.data.Video
import com.example.signlanguage_new.databinding.FragmentYoutubeBinding

class youtubeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels {
        MyViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as SignLanguageApplication).database.VideoDao()
        )
    }
    private var _binding: FragmentYoutubeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentYoutubeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val Dataset= viewModel.result.value
        binding.recyclerView.adapter= Dataset?.let {
            VideoAdapter(requireContext(),
                it,this.lifecycle)
        }
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    }
}
```

And here is the nav_graph and my mainActivity:

**nav_graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.signlanguage_new.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_youtubeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/youtubeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.signlanguage_new.youtubeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_youtube"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_youtube" />
</navigation>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.signlanguage_new

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Retrieve NavController from the NavHostFragment
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        // Set up the action bar for use with the NavController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    /**
     * Handle navigation when the user chooses Up from the action bar.
     */
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

I guess it may have something to do with my adapter for the recyclerview in youtube-fragment because I provide the lifecycle as a parameter for it.

Here it is:

**VideoAdapter**

```
package com.example.signlanguage_new

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.signlanguage_new.data.Video
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView

class VideoAdapter (private val context: Context, private val dataset:List<Video>, private val lifecycle: Lifecycle) :RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {

        val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.videolistitem,parent,false) as YouTubePlayerView
        lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)
        return ItemViewHolder(youTubePlayerView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current=dataset[position]
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        holder.loadVideo(current.ytId)
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataset.size
    }
    class ItemViewHolder(playerView: YouTubePlayerView) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(playerView) {
        val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = playerView
        var youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer? = null
        var currentVideoId: String? = null
        
        fun loadVideo(videoId: String?) {
            currentVideoId = videoId
            if (youTubePlayer == null) return
            if (videoId != null) {
                youTubePlayer!!.cueVideo(videoId, 0F)
            }
        }
        init {
            youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(initializedYouTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    youTubePlayer = initializedYouTubePlayer
                    currentVideoId?.let {
                        youTubePlayer!!.cueVideo(it, 0F)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get to the home fragment instead of leaving the app?

Comment: Why are you using `app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"` if you don't want to remove (pop) `homeFragment` off the back stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment", app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to your navigation action, this means you want to remove the `homeFragment` from back stack. essentially meaning when you press back, `homeFragment` will no longer be there, if you want back button to take you to `homeFragment`, you need to update the action as

```
<action
      android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_youtubeFragment"
      app:destination="@id/youtubeFragment" />
```